# Building a URL dynamically but it's being encoded automatically

Tags: c#, .net-core

Running .NET Core 3.

My code:

`rating = string.Format("<A HREF=\"{0}\">{1}</A>", ratingUrl, ratingText);`

When using the rating variable in my table, it's being automatically HTML encoded.

`<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">@rating</td>`

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">&lt;A HREF=&quot;http://myurl.com/&quot;&gt;Rating&lt;/A&gt;</td>
```

I don't recall seeing this automatic encoding behavior before.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core? Are you using `rating` in a razor (cshtml) page?

Comment: Should go away with either specifying the formatter you need or building your string with string interpolation instead `rating = $"<A HREF=\"{ratingUrl}\">{ratingText}</A>"`

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, in a razor page.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu That's a much cleaner way to do it (and I'm keeping that), but it was still encoding. Gabriel's solution resolved the encoding bit.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the razor engine assumes that you want to display every character in the string on your page, so it helpfully encodes it for you.

But if your string contains HTML that you want rendered as HTML, you can use [`Html.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) to tell it to not encode your string:

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">@Html.Raw(rating)</td>
```